# Auto backup of a folder over a network?

Tags: networking, backup, shared-directory

How to automatic backup a folder or multiple network folder to another computer.

We try always sync.

can any other software is better?

please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://www.dropbox.com/ is's very nice, unfortunately you have to pay, if you need more than 2GB.

Answer (score 0):

I generally just use XCOPY